# How can I get Selection in dashboard with ChartWrapper

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-visualization

I´m trying to get an event in a google dashboard ChartWrapper.

I need that when I select a row i can throw an event and get the selected value.

Can anyone help me or say me how can I get it?

Here´s my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    var data;
    var table;
    var dash_container;
    var myDashboard;
    var stringFilter;
    var myTable;


    function draw() {
        // To see the data that this visualization uses, browse to
      // http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ
      data = new google.visualization.Query(
          'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0Ai3BbtO5JfaodGluSWw0UVFvZ3BDak1nYzVac0RPWGc&pub=1');

      // Send the query with a callback function.
      data.send(handleQueryResponse);


    }
     //fin de draw

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {

      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      table = response.getDataTable();

       // Create a dashboard.  
      dash_container = document.getElementById('dashboard'),  
      myDashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(dash_container);  

      // Define a StringFilter control for the 'Name' column
      stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
       'controlType': 'StringFilter',
       'containerId': 'filter',
       'options': {'filterColumnLabel': 'nombre'}
      }); 

      // Table visualization  
      myTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({  
       'chartType' : 'Table',  
       'containerId' : 'table',
       'view': {'columns': [0]} ,
       'dataTable': table
      });  


    // Register a listener to be notified once the dashboard is ready.
        google.visualization.events.addListener(myDashboard, 'ready', dashboardReady);


      myDashboard.bind(stringFilter, myTable);

      myDashboard.draw(table);


    }
```

**Here´s where I have the problems, because I can get the selection row

```
    function dashboardReady() {

        google.visualization.events.addListener(myTable, 'select', function(event) {

        var selection = myTable.getChart().getSelection();


        // iterate over all selected rows
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            // do something with selection[i].row
          var item = selection[i];
        }
      alert('Fila seleccionada es: '+item.row +' y la Columna: '+item.column);
    });
      }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(draw);
```

Answer (score 2):

To do that, you need to do two things after the chart is drawn:

1. Add a 'ready' event listener to your chart wrapper;
2. Add a 'select' event listener to the table when the chart wrapper is ready.

So, add the following two lines after `myDashboard.draw(table);` in your code

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(myTable , 'ready', function(){
     google.visualization.events.addListener(myTable ,'select', tableSelectHandler);
});


function tableSelectHandler(){
   var selection = myTable.getChart().getSelection();
   alert(data.getValue(selection[0].row,0));
}
```

There will be about 3 seconds delay for the ready function to be triggered, due to a bug I think, see here for more details about the bug report of this issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Modified%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=1470

Answer (score 0):

With Wrapper you have to add one more function to get selected item i.e. getChart()
Like:

```
var selectedItem = wrapper.getChart().getSelection()
```

Remember, Without Wrapper you was getting it by:

```
var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()
```

Answer (score -1):

The code working ...

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(draw);         

  function draw() {
  
    var data = [
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004', 1000,    400],
      ['2005', 1170,    460],
      ['2006', 660,     1120],
      ['2007', 1030,    540]
    ];

    var table = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

    // Create a dashboard.  
    var dash_container = document.getElementById('dashboard');
    var myDashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(dash_container);    

    // Define a StringFilter control.
    var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'StringFilter',
        'containerId': 'filter',
        'options': {'filterColumnLabel': 'Year'}
    }); 

    // Table visualization  
    var myTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({  
        'chartType' : 'Table',  
        'containerId' : 'table',
        'view': {'columns': [0, 1]} ,
        'dataTable': table,
    });  

    myDashboard.bind(stringFilter, myTable);
    myDashboard.draw(table);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(myTable , 'ready',            function(){
          google.visualization.events.addListener(myTable                   ,'select', tableSelectHandler);
        });

    function tableSelectHandler(e){
      var selection = myTable.getChart().getSelection();
      var t=table.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);
      document.getElementById('label1').innerHTML = t;
    }  

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="filter"></div>
 <br>
 <div id="table"></div>
 <br>
 <div id="label1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should provide context to your answer.

Comment: The published code did not work for me. This code that I presented works